# custom XMl works well on dev machine but doesn't work properly on server

Tags: magento2, module, layout, xml, server-setup

Having a strange issue on custom created modules layout xml in 2 different environments.

On **dev machine** all created xmls are getting loaded and executed but when pushed code on server none of the declaration inside xml aren't taken in consideration.

What can cause this behaviour? if the module is called directly than it works

```
{{block class=Vendor\Custom\Block\TopSellers" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list.phtml" name="topsellers"}}
```

How to debug this kind of cases?

I see that module is enabled

I already run these commands

```
rm -rf var/di var/cache/ var/generation
rm -rf pub/static/*

bin/magento setup:upgrade

bin/magento setup:di:compile

bin/magento index:reindex

bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Comment: which error are generated inside log folder?

Comment: system.log, exception.log(here nothing specific to the case and already obsoleted), debug.log, install.log  on local I have debug.log, system.log

Comment: Have you confirmed that everything is the same. i.e. file permissions, php version, sql version, os etc?